# Doctrine2, how to get repositoryClass references added to yaml files

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am currently using this to generate my yaml:

doctrine orm:convert-mapping --force --from-database yml ./yaml

However, this doesn't have the repositoryClass reference in them. Is there a way to do this via CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the repository class manually to the yaml as a repo class has nothing to do with the db schema so convert-mapping is not the tool for the job. Just add the following to your yaml

```
repositoryClass: Repository\MyRepository
```

Where Repository\MyRepository is the fully qualified name of your repo class. You could also then use the CLI to generate the file orm:generate-repositories...